# How to backup data from eclipse

Tags: metadata, eclipse

I want to take backup of my data on the basis of object and his field.
object=case  business unit=airlife

i want to backup triggers,clasess etc.
could anyone plz tell me  ....is there any way for this ?

Comment: Is this the metadata or the actual data or both that you are looking to back up?

Comment: Both .. i am looking

Answer (score 0):

You can take backup using Eclipse or Sublime Text 3 (with MavensMate).

Please go through below you tube videos you can understand easily.

- 1 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8vencxEEgCY
- 2 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdKtk2CepoQ